# Debugging crash with seemingly corrupted Linux stack trace

Tags: linux, debugging, stack

I am working with a client who is debugging a crash in my code, using my libraries in their product. I don't have access to the client's dev environment. I have provided them with my .so libraries and associated .pdb debugging info. (The debugging info was created by compiling code with -g, then the .pdb files were created using `objcopy --only-keep-debug`, and finally the .so files had the symbols removed using `objcopy --strip-all`.) Client loaded the symbols manually into gdb using the command `add-symbol-file libBDR.so.5.1.4.pdb`. Client has confirmed they are using the correct libs and debugging symbols. The stack trace provided to me:

```
libc.so.6!__libc_siglongjmp(struct __jmp_buf_tag * env, int val) Line 32      C
libpthread.so.0!longjmp_compat(struct __jmp_buf_tag * env, int val) Line 62   C
libCT.so![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]   
libCT.so!CTInit   
libBDR.so.5.1.4![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]   
libBDR.so.5.1.4!BDRPublic::BDRInit(BDRPublic::tBDRInitData const*, BDRPublic::I_Error&)
libcalappl.so!BDRPublic::BDR_Initialize(BDRPublic::pBDRWrapperInitData initData) Line 7488      C++
libcalappl.so!JPStartBDR(JPPriv * jpPriv, JPFrontOpts * jpOpts,  bdrDLLVersion, BDRPublic::sBDRWrapperConfigDataBuffer * bdrConfigDataBuffer) Line 2240     C++
libcalappl.so!appl_start() Line 392 C++
libcalupdl.so!appl_Main(struct pdf_Handle * hndl) Line 125  C
libcalbrainlib.so!ResEntryPoint(void * param) Line 820      C
libcalbrainlib.so!SI_TaskStartUp(void * pvParam) Line 639   C
libcalbasics.so!s_TaskStartUp(void * param) Line 4445 C++
libcalbasics.so!s_TaskStartUpPthread(void * pvParam) Line 4549    C++
libpthread.so.0!start_thread(void * arg) Line 477     C
libc.so.6!clone() Line 95     C++
```

My code is libBDR.so/libCT.so; everything below that is the client's code. The "Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code" doesn't make sense, as all the code is C/C++ and there should be no JIT code/environment. How can I get them to provide a better stack trace with the missing frame info in my code?